# Page to display online users with photos

Tags: php, mysql, database, social-networking

I am attempting to create a social network so far I have got as far as registration form passing valid data to the database, I currently have two tables....

**Member table**
- firstName
- lastName
- mobileNumber (PK)
- postcode
- city
 with members details etc..

**User table**
- userID (PK) AUTO INCREMENT
- username
- password
- profilepic
- accountType

In my web site I am attempting to have a page where users can browse other users and they can also select a page that will show all online users along with their profile picture and username. I was wondering how I would go about this or if any one that has done similar types of webpages would give me any tips, at the moment I can only see counters to display the online users as an integer. I am doing my project with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Mate, plan before you execute. :)

Please ask specific question if you have trouble in getting things done. Also try to do your homework yourself and ask questions here if you have some problem or error then post questions. There are youtube tutorials where you can find help.

Please post your codes, to show that you have tried and then someone will help you.

Comment: Break down your project into small bits and start executing one by one, if you have any trouble getting things done post a question on it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to think about how you can know if a user is online or not. In your member table, do you have a field with a time-stamp when they last logged in? If so, you can do this simply from your MYSQL query to pull any members where the timestamp was within the last 5 or so minutes. Your query might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `last_logged_in` > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

But, I'm a little confused about the differences between users and members. If you aren't using a particular framework or tools for your database work, you might want to research PDO for PHP and how to use it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you this seems quiet simple now you explained it, For my database I was using an ER diagram to plan it so member table inherits from the user table, I did this for normalisation to make sure all composite keys are in separate tables